# groovy configslurper Environment No such property when compiled to jar

Tags: groovy

I'm having a trouble reading an environment configuration stored in a .groovy script from a jar created as a compiled version of my main script.  The script version runs fine.  The "sandbox3" reference in the error message refers to an environment defined in the config file.  This it the error message I get:

```
server_control_web_services>runobiadmin2 -e sandbox3
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: sandbox3 for class: script_from_command_line
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: sandbox3 for class: script_from_command_line
    at script_from_command_line.run(script_from_command_line:1)
```

Groovy 2.4.5
When running the original script the code below behaves as expected setting config to the environment passed from the command line.  obieeadmincfg.groovy is located in the same directory as the jar file.

```
URL url = OBIEEAdmin.class.getClassLoader().getResource('obieeadmincfg.groovy')
config = new ConfigSlurper(opt.e).parse(url)
```

Comment: What s runobiadmin2?

Comment: It's just a cmd file that runs the script  "java -classpath .  -jar runobieeadmin.jar %*"